# Another template for a detailed view of material in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I have the menu item and category blog bound to this item. This menu item display blog category and have "product_catalog" template. But, when i go into detailed view of the material, i see material in this same pattern. I want to show the detailed materials of this menu item display in a different pattern(an example "product_detail").

It is possible?

I use Joomla 1.7

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to do this other than select an alternative layout for every item you put in the category you want to look different. In com_content, you can only select an alternative layout for all articles, not articles within a particular category.

If you plan to have a lot of articles with alternative layouts, I would seriously consider using K2 instead. Rather than alternative layouts, K2 uses subtemplates. When you create a subtemplate, you include files that define the layout for the category view and the item view so each category can have a unique details page.